# brother printer after installing drivers

Tags: drivers, brother

So I installed the brother drivers using the installer and now I see files starting with "uninstaller" and some debian files in my downloads directory along with the linux installer file. Are these the drivers? Also am I allowed to move in them outside of my downloads directory?

Sorry if this is a dumb question I am new to ubuntu.

The files are:

- uninstaller_brscan-skey
- uninstaller_brscan4
- uninstaller_MFCJ485DW
- mfcj485dwlpr-1.0.0-0a.i386.deb
- mfcj485dwcupswrapper-1.0.0-0a.i386.deb
- brscan4-0.4.9-1.amd64.deb
- mfcj485dwlpr-1.0.0-0.i386.deb
- mfcj485dwcupswrapper-1.0.0-0.i386.deb
- brscan-skey-0.2.4-1.amd64.deb
- linux-brprinter-installer-2.2.1-1 [this file I downloaded from the brother website and executed the script]

Also all of the files except for the linux-brprinter-installer have a lock symbol on the lower right corner of the thumbnail for the file.

Comment: @user535733 I have added file names

Comment: Thank you @user535733. If you want you could post your comment as an answer and I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can move any (or all) of those files to anywhere you wish. None need to stay in Downloads.

You should be able to delete all of them without breaking your working printer.

You may encounter difficulty moving or deleting files with the lock symbol -- that means you don't own them. Open a terminal and use sudo to move them, delete them, or change their ownership.